# iTunes Connect, Changed date at "X Days ago"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I submitted my first app to the iOS App store. 
For 7 days I'm waiting.

On the iOS iTunes Connect app at
the binary page it said "7 Days ago".

Today it said "12 Hours ago". I didn't made changes to anything.
Still "Waiting for review"

Nothing found on the web about this.

Am I at the start of the queue again? And why?

Comment: May be testers of apple are testing your app, not a big issue, wait until your app accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal. You can see Average App Store Review Times [here](http://appreviewtimes.com).

Comment: Thanks for the link ChikabuZ. I check iTunes connect almost hourly. The wait makes me crazy :D